# Props data are not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem rendering my props data
Here I'm trying to pass props to a component with mapped data from a sample data set

```
const weatherComponents = weatherData.items.map(weather => {
  return(
    <div key={weather.forecasts.area}>
      <WeatherForecast 
        name={weather.forecasts.area}
        condition={weather.forecasts.forecast}>
      </WeatherForecast>
    </div>
    )})
return(
    {weatherComponents} )
```

This is the component

```
function WeatherForecast(props) {
return(
    <div>
        <p>Name: {props.name}</p>
        <p>Condition: {props.condition}</p>
    </div>
)}
```

This is the sample data set

```
   {
 "area_metadata": [
   {
     "name": "Yishun",
     "label_location": {
       "latitude": 1.418,
       "longitude": 103.839
     }
   }
 ],"items": [
   {
     "forecasts": [
     {
       "area": "Yishun"
       "forecast" : "cloudy"
     }
   ]}
 ]}
```

In my browser, it shows *Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.* and the data are not rendering, it only appears "Name: " without the area name from the data set. Am I mapping the data in the wrong way? Help TT

Comment: `weather.forecasts` is an array itself; both `weather.forecasts.area` and `weather.forecasts.forecast` are `undefined`. You need `weather.forecasts[0].area` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options ... well, 3.

1. You need an array in "area_metadata" and "items":

*1.1. The fast solution:*

```
const weatherComponents = weatherData.items.map(weather => {
  return(
    <div key={weather.forecasts[0].area}>
      <WeatherForecast 
        name={weather.forecasts[0].area}
        condition={weather.forecasts[0].forecast}>
      </WeatherForecast>
    </div>
  )
})

return({weatherComponents})
```

*1.2 The right solution:*

```
const weatherComponents = weatherData.items.map(weather => {

  return weather.forecasts.map( casts => (
    <div key={casts.area}>
      <WeatherForecast 
        name={casts.area}
        condition={casts.forecast}>
      </WeatherForecast>
    </div>
  ))
})

return({weatherComponents})
```

*2. You do not need an array:*

```
{
  "area_metadata": [
    {
      "name": "Yishun",
      "label_location": {
        "latitude": 1.418,
        "longitude": 103.839
      }
    }
  ],
  "items": [
    {
      "forecasts": {
        "area": "Yishun"
        "forecast" : "cloudy"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks bud! The 1.2 solution works great and just what I wanted.. But I'm still abit confused, so does it means for each of the arrays, there's has to be a map function for each of them? 2 arrays (items & forecasts), then 2 map function?

Comment: Yes, 2 arrays, 2 map functions. In the first map function, you iterate through the items to access objects. In this case called weather. These objects again contain arrays (forecasts) with objects. Of course you have to iterate through it again. Unless (and therefore the 2nd solution) you have the option to change the data set and you do not need an array in forecasts. If you have only one object in the array anyway, you can omit the array or use the fast solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
const weatherComponents = weatherData.items.map(weather => {
  return(
    <div key={weather.forecasts.area}>
      <WeatherForecast 
        name={weather.forecasts.area}
        condition={weather.forecasts.forecast}>
      </WeatherForecast>
    </div>
    )})
return(
    {weatherComponents} )
```

with

```
const weatherComponents = weatherData.items.map(weather => {
     const {area, forecast} = weather.forecasts[0];
      return(
        <div key={area}>
          <WeatherForecast 
            name={area}
            condition={forecast}>
          </WeatherForecast>
        </div>
        )})
    return(
        {weatherComponents} )
```

Comment: this actually works for a specified index (one area only), but not for the whole set of data (all the area from the data set). Thanks though!